# SQLite in Android - Syntax Error in CREATE TABLE

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have been working on an Android app for a while and have recently started getting into making a database for the app. That being said I am currently having an issue with my `CREATE TABLE` commands. I have run these through SQL fiddle and it doesn't seem to think there is a problem, but Eclipse does.

```
CREATE TABLE team (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                   teamName TEXT , 
                   teamYear TEXT , 
                   teamLevel TEXT )

CREATE TABLE matchs (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                     oponentName TEXT , 
                     matchDate TEXT , 
                     teamId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                     FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES team (_id ))

CREATE TABLE matchSet (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                       setNumber TEXT , 
                       matchId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                       FOREIGN KEY (matchId) REFERENCES matchs (_id ))

CREATE TABLE player (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                     playerNumber TEXT , 
                     playerPosition TEXT , 
                     playerFirstName TEXT , 
                     playerLastName TEXT , 
                     playerNickname TEXT , 
                     playerPic TEXT , 
                     playerTagline TEXT , 
                     teamId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                     FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES team (_id ))

CREATE TABLE par (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                  action TEXT , 
                  result TEXT , 
                  playerId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                  FOREIGN KEY (playerId) REFERENCES player (_id ) , 
                  setId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                  FOREIGN KEY (setId) REFERENCES matchSet (_id ))

CREATE TABLE stats (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
                    playerId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                    FOREIGN KEY (playerId) REFERENCES player (_id ) , 
                    setId INTEGER NOT NULL  , 
                    FOREIGN KEY (setId) REFERENCES matchSet (_id ) , 
                    attackKill TEXT , 
                    attackError TEXT , 
                    attackTotal TEXT , 
                    attackPercentage TEXT , 
                    setAssist TEXT , 
                    serveAce TEXT ,
                    serveError TEXT , 
                    serveZero TEXT , 
                    passRating TEXT , 
                    blockSolo TEXT , 
                    blockAssist TEXT , 
                    blockError TEXT , 
                    genBhe TEXT , 
                    pts TEXT )
```

The error is being thrown on the creation of the par table near the `setId` foreign key. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what error might that be?

Comment: It was a syntax error. Sorry. Forgot to add that I guess. Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints at the end of the `CREATE TABLE`.

Compare a Fiddle using your SQL above  with this [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/10b71).

The first one returned an error:

> could not prepare statement (1 near "setId": syntax error)